# "Humble Project Starter"

Tags: single-word-requests

Trying to think of a word or phrase for someone who was instrumental in getting a project started but was only minimally involved with the project itself. Needs to be humble.

**Example:**

> She was one of the people who requested the course of study and was
>   part of the focus group in determining the curriculum. She was also
>   one of the first people to graduate with this newly created degree.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it's "humble" enough for you, but [***pioneer***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pioneer):

> one who is first or among the earliest
>   in any field of inquiry, enterprise, or progress

seems to capture the meaning you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try [pathfinder](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pathfinder)

> a person or group that is the first to do something and that makes it possible for others to do the same thing.

You see, in a way, people may walk on a path without the pathfinder but if the pathfinder hadn't found it, they wouldn't be walking.